# Excel virtual memory issues

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2007 with Win7 32bit. I have downloaded Process Explorer to get more information on processes running.

If I put a formula in A1 =sum(if(B:J=0, 1, 0)) and so a ctl-shift-enter (for an array) it works but the virtual memory shoots up to about 800+ MB. If I try to put that same formula into A2 I get "out of resources" error. I see the virtual memory spike up to about 1.2 GIG when I get the error. I'm guessing it gets over 2 GIG (since that seems to be the limit for Excel 2007) but the Process Explorer just doesn't show it fast enough.

If I delete the formulas the virtual memory still stays up around 800+ MB. I can't seem to reduce the virtual memory used. If then again try to put that 1 formula in I get "out of resources" and now I can't even put 1 of those formulas in where I could before. It's like it's not deallocating the virtual memory used.

I'm aware that Win 7 64-bit and Excel 2010 64 bit has like 8 TB of virtual memory but if the virtual memory isn't getting deallocated it seems like a memory leak.

The formula is just a test to get the idea which is many array formulas in a workbook seem to suffer from this.

Any ideas of what I can do in this case besides upgrading?

Comment: Your Array causing the virtual memory will still be in the undo stack.  I would suspect that's why the memory doesn't clear up.

Comment: I suggest you stop using whole column references in array formulas (if(B:J=0, 1, 0) creates over 9 million cells that need to be referenced and compared with 9 million virtual cells containing zero to create 9 virtual million cells containing 0 or 1, so I am surprised that the memory only goes up to 800 MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a fresh workbook and use those column formulas over the worksheet does the memory spike? If any/all the cells in the column have been "touched", then Excel will treat them as blank cells and use them in the formula. If they've never been touched, then they're not present and Excel shouldn't try to load them into memory.

If your workbook is just massive, you're probably stuck, though it might be possible to restructure your formulas to work over smaller sections of cells, then run those results over another set of formulas to get your final results.

Comment: This is over a fresh workbook and the memory does spike to 800+ MB. It starts out around 100 or so when I first open the fresh book.

Comment: Just a note, I just tried it on Windows 7 with Excel 2007 on an x64 machine and didn't have a memory spike.